# Accessing image from a specific folder in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Can someone please explain to me what the code below isnt working?

```
myFolderdepth = 'C:\Users\owner\Desktop'; %Specify Directory to get image from
Depth = dir (fullfile(myFolderdepth,'shower_depth','*.png'))%%Get images from file named     shower_depth
Depth_name = {Depth.name}'; %gets the name
figure;
imshow(Depth_name{3})
```

The error message I get is as follows:
Error using getImageFromFile (line 11)
Cannot find the specified file:
"Depth_003.png".

The directory I am working in is: C:\Users\owner\Desktop

The name of the pictures are Depth_001,Depth_002,Depth_003,......

Oddly enough, I have another folder that has images and if I change the 'shower_depth' to the other folder name, it works fine.

Thank you!
P.S I did some further experimentation, it turns out its because of the way the image is named; if its Depth_01.png thats fine it works but Depth_001.png is not okay

Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following command:

```
Depth = dir (fullfile(myFolderdepth,'shower_depth','*.png'))
```

only gets the **relative** names of the files.  This means that the file names are only retrieved, **not the full path to the file**.  Take a look at the error that you're getting:

> Error using `getImageFromFile` (line 11)
>
> Cannot find the specified file: `"Depth_003.png"`.

Do you see the path of where your images in the above file name?  Nope!  You only see the file **stored in the directory**.  You need to specify the full path of where the image is located.

What you need to do is append the directory as well as the image itself as the string you supply to `imshow`:

```
myFolderdepth = 'C:\Users\owner\Desktop'; %Specify Directory to get image from
Depth = dir (fullfile(myFolderdepth,'shower_depth','*.png'))%%Get images from file named     shower_depth
Depth_name = {Depth.name}'; %gets the name
figure;
imshow(fullfile(myFolderDepth, Depth_name{3})); %// CHANGE HERE
```

Answer (score -1):

`Depth_name` is only the image name. You have to read the image before show it.  The modified code is below:

```
im = imread(Depth_name{3});
imshow(Depth_name{3});
```

Comment: Not necessarily.  If you provide a string, `imread` will automatically assume it's a path, and it'll read from the path and show the image.  Try doing `imread('cameraman.tif');`.  MATLAB has a `cameraman.tif` image as part of its system path, and this will show you a 256 x 256 image.  You can also do: `im = imread('camerman.tif'); imshow(im);`.  Consult the `imshow` documentation here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshow.html#btp8up0-2_1.  You should consider changing your answer to incorporate this information, or removing your answer all together as I'm tempted to downvote it.